# Check existence of multiple network shared files

Tags: windows, scripting, network-share, batch

Let's say I have a list of files (`files.txt`), which looks like:

```
\\myshare\file1
\\myshare\file2
\\myshare\file3
```

How is it possible to check via a batch script (windows) to check if those files exist and output this? I tried with `if exists \\path\file`, but it always tells me that the path can not be used syntactically at that point.

Comment: What kind of file sharing protocol are you using? SMB? NFS?

Comment: How can I find out? It is a simple Windows share. So I guess it is SMB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete script. It can be modified to use with other stuff

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (list.txt) do (
 if exist %%s (
  echo %%s found
  echo %%s >> sharesfound.txt
 ) else (
  echo %%s NOT found
  echo %%s >> sharesmissing.txt
 )
)
```

Comment: BTW you can get a list of all shares by command net share

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Based on the format of your path, I think that you're referring to SMB: in that case, either you can mount the share (eg. with `mount.cifs`) and check as if it's a local file, or you can use `smbclient` to check if the file exist remotely:</strike>

```
smbclient //host/share -U username -c "ls filetocheck"
```

The result will be in `$?`, and it will be zero if file exists, `1` otherwise.

On Windows, you can use `if exist \\server\share goto label` (actually, you can issue any CMD command instead of `goto`)

Comment: Please check my question, I was asking for a batch solution (windows). Thanks for your effort though!

Comment: Sorry I don't know why I was so certain that you were asking for Linux. However, I updated my answer :-)

Comment: I guess it should be `if exist` instead of `if exists`.